# WMI Error in Windows Server 2008 (WMI Provider)

Tags: c++, windows-services, windows-server-2008, wmi

I've implemented a WMI provider (Window service, Instance, Methods and Properties provider).
It works fine on Windows Server 2003, but when it run on Windows Server 2008 with **non-local administrator** user, I cannot query it.

The error I get is `0x8004101d - unexpected error`.

When the service user is a local admin everything is OK.

What could it be???

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the problem was that I didn't specify the `HostingModel`, so it defaulted to `NetworkServiceHost`. The one needed one is `LocalSystemHostOrSelfHost` (that is the default in prior to Vista OSs).